# How to inject beans when Jackson deserializes a JSON request?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Spring web application that receives objects that needs to be injected as beans. Is there an easy way to instruct Jackson to create the instances as Spring bean on deserialization without having to implement a custom deserializer?

My code looks like this:

I have a class `A` in which some properties are autowired and some are not.

```java
@Component
public class A {

    private String value;

    @Autowired
    private Obj autowiredObj;

    // getter & setter
}
```

Another class `B` has several autowired objects that are similar to class `A`. When a class `B` object is sent via Jackson, I want to send only some values of the class `A` like objects, but not the class `A` objects themselves.

```java
@Component
public class B {

    @Autowired
    @JsonIgnore
    private A instanceA;

    public String getValue() {
        return instanceA.getValue();
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        instanceA.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

My Spring controller looks like this.

```java
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/receive",
            consumes = { "application/json" },
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void receiveB(@RequestBody B instanceB) {
        System.out.println("Value: " + instanceB.getValue());
    }
}
```

On deserialization Jackson is currently trying to instantiate an object without Spring. Therefore the autowired `instanceA` in class `B` is null and when Jackson tries to set the value in class `B`, it gives following response message (`400`):

```
JSON parse error: null; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: N/A\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 27] (through reference chain: B[\"value\"])
```

But I want Jackson to get a class `B` bean from Spring and paste the received data into it. Is there any deserialization setting or annotation to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want Jackson to get a class B bean from Spring and paste the
>   received data into it.

There is no annotation that would do that. Technically it is possible, but requires some efforts. You can implement your own deserializer and register it via ObjectMapper. In this deserializer, instead of creating a new instance of the bean, you would look up a Spring bean, then "manually" set each of its attributes.

I would discourage you from deserializing into Spring beans. I would suggest that you define some normal Java bean (not a Spring bean) and use it for serializting/deserializing. You can use it both your Spring beans A and B to keep the state. That could be easier.

Comment: ATM there seems to be no other way then doing it "manually". Thanks!